# Create a regular expression using data extracted from an XML file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an xml file, that has nodes with text like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"  encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<country>
  <name> France </name>
  <city> Paris </city>
  <region>
    <name> Nord-Pas De Calais </name>
    <population> 3996 </population>
    <city> Lille </city>
  </region>
  <region>
    <name> Valle du Rhone </name>
    <city> Lyon </city>
    <city> Valence </city>
  </region>
</country>
```

What I want to get is values like this:

```
country -> name.city.region*
region  -> name.(population|epsilon).city*
name    -> epsilon
city    -> epsilon
population -> epsilon
```

I can't figure out a method to do that

Comment: You **should not** use regex for parsing xml. Use a parser instead.
Look at [THIS](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html) link

Comment: @SalmanA you don't see the question , im parsing my XML file using JDOM parser , and i want get the regular expression associate to the XML file

Comment: @his im not parsing the XML file with a regular expression , i want to generate the regular expression

Comment: Do you want to create the grammar? Like a DTD or an XSD?

Answer (score 2):

I have added a sample program. Please continue with reading same way.

```
public class TextXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new File("text.xml"));

            // list of country elements
            NodeList listOfCountry = doc.getElementsByTagName("country");
            for (int s = 0; s < listOfCountry.getLength(); s++) {

                Node countyNode = listOfCountry.item(s);

                if (countyNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element countyElement = (Element) countyNode;

                    NodeList nameList = countyElement.getElementsByTagName("name");
                    // we have only one name. Element Tag
                    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                    System.out.println("Name : " + nameElement.getTextContent());

                    NodeList cityList = countyElement.getElementsByTagName("city");
                    // we have only one name. Element Tag
                    Element cityElement = (Element) cityList.item(0);
                    System.out.println("City : " + cityElement.getTextContent());

                    NodeList regionList = countyElement.getElementsByTagName("region");
                    // we have only one name. Element Tag
                    Element regionElement = (Element) regionList.item(0);
                    System.out.println("Region : " + regionElement.getTextContent());

                    //continue further same way.
                }

            }

        } catch (SAXParseException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Exception x = e.getException();
            ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you will have to test it your self.

Comment: You can also try with JAXB. This is good and clean way to read data from a XML content.